# How to rectify the issue with the below flow?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a mule flow as under

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="f1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\input" responseTimeout="10000"
        doc:name="File" />
</flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="f2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080"
        doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <flow-ref name="flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\outputfile"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
</flow>
```

I am trying to move/upload multiple files from source to destination (can be anything e.g. FTP or File outbound etc..) by using the flow.

The reason for doing in this way is that I want to invoke the job from CLI(Command Line Interface) using CURL.

But it is not working....

### Edited

I need to pick up some files(multiple files) from a particular folder located in my hard drive. And then move those to some outbound process which can be FTP site or some other hard drive location.
But this flow needs to be invoked from CLI.

### Edited (Based on David's answer)

I now have the flow as under

```
<flow name="filePickupFlow" doc:name="flow1" initialState="stopped">
     <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            
      <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="ERROR" />
</flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="flow2">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/file-pickup/start" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
  
  <expression-component>
        app.registry.filePickupFlow.start();
    </expression-component>
 
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\outputfile" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

</flow>
```

I am getting couple of problems

a) I am getting an error that - *Attribute initialState is not defined as a valid property of flow*

[image]

However, if I remove that attribute, the flow continues without waiting for `"http://localhost:8080/file-pickup/start"` to fire up.

b) The files are not moved to the destination folder

So how can I do so?

Comment: DO you want to read the file when it is available or   The file should be read only on triggering the read based on a call or event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference a flow that has an inbound endpoint in it because such a flow is already active and consuming events from its inbound endpoint so you can't invoke it on demand.

The following, tested on Mule 3.3.1, shows how to start a "file pickup flow" on demand from an HTTP request.

```
<flow name="filePickupFlow" initialState="stopped">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="///tmp/mule/input" />
    <!-- Do something with the file: here we just log its content -->
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="ERROR" />
</flow>

<flow name="filePickupStarterFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/file-pickup/start"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <expression-component>
        app.registry.filePickupFlow.start();
    </expression-component>
    <set-payload value="File Pickup successfully started" />
</flow>
```

HTTP GETting `http://localhost:8080/file-pickup/start` would then start the `filePickupFlow`, which in turn will process the files in `/tmp/mule/input`.

Note that it is up to you to configure the `file:connector` for what behavior it must have for files it processes, either deleting them or moving them to another directory are two main options.

Comment: I have added the requirement. When the Http endpoint is invoke, the files needs to be picked up from a particular location and moved to some outbound process(may be FTP or other hard drive location).Kindly let me know if I need to provide any other information

Comment: Thanks, I've reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sir, one more stuff.The process should pick up all the files(multiple files) inside the folder and not any particular one. i.e. it should pick all the files from /tmp/input and not only /tmp/input/debuglog.txt...so how should I change it?

Comment: Wow, that's a completely different requirement then! Is the directory where the files are picked-up from fixed or passed by the HTTP call?

Comment: It is a fixed directory and not being passed from Http call....say the initial directory being C:\MyInput

Comment: Alright, I completely reviewed my answer based on these latest info.

Comment: Hi,I have 2 problems now  (a) I am getting an error: - Attribute initialState is not defined as a valid property of flow (b) Files are not moving to the destination folder. How to solve this? Updated the question

Comment: a) Disregard, this is a typical Studio bogus error, the config runs just fine. b) You've put the `file:outbound-endpoint` in the flow that **controls** the `filePickupFlow`. This is wrong. You should put it in the `filePickupFlow` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in this case a File inbound to read a file on demand will not be helpful.

Please try if the follwoing way.

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="f2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080"
        doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="fileLoader"></spring-object>
    </component>
   <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\outputfile"
       responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
</flow>
```

So the Custom component will be a Class which reads the file from your specified location.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mule Requester for a clean solution. See the details in the blog entry [Introducing the Mule Requester](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/).