# Mule 3.2 Flow Initialization in a specific order

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-flow

I have two flows in mule. I want to make one of them start , only after the other has been up and running for a while. how can I do that? Thanks

```
<flow name="newHttpClientRequestProcessor" doc:name="newHttpClientRequestProcessor">
```

```
 <flow name="RestNewHttpClientRequestFlow" doc:name="RestNewHttpClientRequestFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8082" path="subscription" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.citi.isg.rest.endpoints.RestNewHttpClientEndpoint"/>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what I replied to this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633484/387927

- Configure the flow that must not be initially started with `initialState="stopped"`
- Whenever you want to start it, use the following MEL expression: `app.registry.FLOWNAME.start();`, replacing `FLOWNAME` with the name of the flow you want to start.